# Modifying nested state fails to update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why `setState` is not working for me?

On change event, I am setting a state for array.

```
handleonChange(x) {
    var newArray = ['Hello', 'Dear'];

    const clonedState = Object.assign({}, this.state);

    clonedState.trans.value = x;
    clonedState.accList = newArray

    this.setState(clonedState);
}
```

It updates the `trans.value` but `accList` does not set.

Comment: Can you list your entire state tree? That will help with debugging.

Answer (score 2):

why not just try setting state with this syntax (this way you won't have to clone the object, just declare how you want the state to be mutated)

```
this.setState(previousState => {
  trans:
    {
      ...previousState.trans,
      value: x,
    },
  accList: newArray
});
```

Comment: using spread operator neither value is getting rederred on ui nor accList. There is an issue the way i am handling array in state.